Power BI Dedicated Capacity Load Assessment Tool - csv file not being generated
I've been getting acquainted with the Realistic Load Testing tool or the "Capacity Load Assessment Tool" that Matt Lakin has been showing in his YouTube videos for load testing Power Bi. I've been running into a couple of issues where the tool (browser refreshes) doesn't stop except for hitting the Enter Key. The refreshes continue on past the parameters set in the PBIReport.JSON file.
Also, the test report is not being generated with the csv file.
The Git Repo has been archived since Jun 13, 2024 and there's no way to enter issues or get answers.
My only other way of load testing the reports is using TrueClient but if I can get this tool working a small handful of VM's I'd rather do this instead.

the best tool I know to perform load testing is Apache JMeter (https://jmeter.apache.org/). it comes with a lot of customization, a nice UI and a nice community driven support (with tutorials). It is rather easy to use and can generate reports. Consider taking a look at it.
